# Find continuous records with equal values in each group

Tags: sql-server

I have a table named "MachineHealth". Here is the sample data:

| Date | MachineId | IsBad |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-01-05 | 1 | 1 |
| 2020-01-04 | 1 | 1 |
| 2020-01-03 | 1 | 1 |
| 2020-01-02 | 1 | 0 |
| 2020-01-01 | 1 | 1 |
| 2020-01-05 | 2 | 1 |
| 2020-01-04 | 2 | 1 |
| 2020-01-03 | 2 | 0 |
| 2020-01-02 | 2 | 0 |
| 2020-01-01 | 2 | 1 |

I want to find continuous 1 count in field `IsBad` group by `MachineId`, that means the number of days that a machine is continuously bad for the most recent time. For example, the query on above data should return:

| MachineId | ContinuousBadDays |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 2 |

How to write this sql?

Comment: You have 2 rows for MachineId 1 with a date of 2020-01-05.  Is that valid in your scenario?

Comment: @ScottHodgin Thanks for reminding. I have edited the question. It should be only one record for each machine in each day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your duplicate `Dates` for `MachineId = 1` was an accident (as Scott pointed out) something like this should be what you're after:

```
WITH CTE_GoodDates_Sorted AS
(
    SELECT MachineId, [Date], ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY MachineId ORDER BY [Date] DESC) AS SortId -- Generates a unique ID for each row within each MachineId, then resets on the next MachineId
    FROM MachineHealth
    WHERE IsBad = 0 -- Only want good Dates so we can get the last good Date per MachineId later
)

SELECT MH.MachineId, SUM(MH.IsBad) AS ContinuousBadDays
FROM MachineHealth AS MH
INNER JOIN CTE_GoodDates_Sorted AS GD
    ON MH.MachineId = GD.MachineId
    AND MH.[Date] > GD.[Date] -- Ensures we only get rows that came after the good Date
WHERE GD.SortId = 1 -- Using the auto-generate unique ID (within each MachineId), ensures we only have the latest good Date for each MachineId to compare to in the previous INNER JOIN
GROUP BY MH.MachineId
```

This uses the [`ROW_NUMBER()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) [**window function**](https://www.brentozar.com/sql-syntax-examples/window-function-examples-sql-server/) to get the latest `Date` no accidents occurred on per each `MachineId` in a **CTE** then uses that **CTE** to join to filter down the results to only the most recent continuous bad `Dates`. The final query then does a `GROUP BY` on `MachineId` and sums the `IsBad` field to get the total days (though you probably can even substitute that for a `COUNT(1)` instead if your IsBad field at most has a value of 1).

Comment: Thanks so much. This works for me. The solution looks simple that I just need to find the latest good date and count the dates from that day.

Comment: In case of some machines are bad in all days, we cannot find the latest good date. So we can union these machines:

`UNION
SELECT MachineId, COUNT(1) AS ContinuousBadDays
FROM MachineHealth
GROUP BY MachineId
HAVING COUNT(1) == SUM(IsBad)`

Comment: @LeoXu Yes good point, and a smart solution. That's probably similar to how I would add those Machines with all bad days back in as well. :)